# How to return the value of a nested key in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The collection is called `"baseCharges"`

```
{
    photos: {
        under1500: 100,
        between1501_2000: 125,
        between2001_3000: 150,
        between3001_4000: 175,
        between4001_5000: 275,
        between5001_6000: 375,
        between6001_7000: 475,
        between7001_8000: 575,
        between8001_9000: 675,
        between9001_10000: 775,
        between10001_11000: 875
    },
    twilights: {
        under1500: 100,
        between1501_2000: 125,
        between2001_3000: 150,
        between3001_4000: 175,
        between4001_5000: 275,
        between5001_6000: 375,
        between6001_7000: 475,
        between7001_8000: 575,
        between8001_9000: 675,
        between9001_10000: 775,
        between10001_11000: 875
    },
    _id: "B8RCdQp8kuL9r6KdT"
}
```

All I want to return is the value for `baseCharges.photos.under1500`

I want to query the keys and have it return "100" as a **value** that I can then store in a variable, not as a pointer.

I've checked the other threads here on MongoDB but nothing is working for me.

```
db.baseCharges.find({ "photos.under1500" : 1 })
```

doesn't work.

```
db.baseCharges.find("photos.under1500")
```

doesn't work.

```
db.baseCharges.findOne({"photos.under1500" : 1 })
```

is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be close. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the value return so this may be answering the wrong question, but you can get the desired data just adding an (in this case) empty condition to your find. Your existing query is missing the search criteria part.

```
db.baseCharges.find({}, { _id:0, "photos.under1500" : 1 })
```

That will return the field you want (with no condition, that is for all entries)

EDIT: If you want a single value (from the first/single result row), you'll need to get the first document from the cursor find() returns, and use dot notation to get what you need;

```
db.baseCharges.find().next().photos.under1500
```

Comment: All I'm trying to do is have the console return "100", which is the value associated with `baseCharges.photos.under1500`.

When I do `db.baseCharges.find({}, { _id:0, "photos.under1500" : 1 })` I get `{ "photos" : { "under1500" : 100 } }`

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny Updated, may be more what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, but there has GOT to be an easier, less verbose way to do it, doesn't there? I mean, the entire point of a document-database is to be able to drill down and grab the info you want by following the keys, as if you were following a JSON API, right? In which case, simply going to `baseCharges.photos.under1500` should take you directly to the piece of data which is "100" (baseCharges/photos/under1500 would be the JSON API equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it.

This collection `baseCharges` only has one entry, so the following code worked:

```
db.baseCharges.findOne().photos.under1500
```

My issue is that I'm not used to the MongoDB way of working for a single item.

I know that with collections having multiple entries I have to first do a `find` by an `_id` or a unique combination of criteria to start drilling down the data.

But since this collection only has one entry, I figured that I could just use a straight heirarchical way of doing it. There's only one entry. An ID shouldn't be needed, so I thought simply doing `db.baseCharges.photos.under1500` would do.

BUT that's not the way it works. Even when there is only one entry in a collection, you still have to `find` it and then drill down into the data you want.